# Window.Icon can not be found

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I did the following:

I went to Properties -> Resources and added an existing file (iconSmall.ico). As a result, the file gets placed in the "Resources" folder of the solution. Now I want to use the Icon in my MainWindow, so I typed: Icon="" in the Window XAML-declaration and I immediately got the suggestion to use my .ico from my Resources. I tab-complete and get this:

`Icon="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/iconSmall.ico"`

Now, when I start the application, it says, that the directory can not be found, although the file is present in the exact location in the file system/the solution explorer and Visual Studio even suggested me the icon.

How is this possible?

Regards

Comment: Try to use "pack://application:,,,/NameOfDllWhereYourResourcesReside;component/FolderPath/iconSmall.ico"

Comment: I forgot to set "Build Action" to "Resource" and "Copy to Output Directory" to 
"Copy if newer". A classic example of a mental block.


Thanks, @Engineer Spock